# Disabled AD Users Based on List

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a simple script which will tell me what AD Users are Disabled in a List.

```
<#
512 = Enabled
514 = Disabled
66048 = Enabled, password never expires
66050 = Disabled, password never expires
#>


Write-Host "Enter Full File Path for User List"
$UserListPath = Read-Host "Path"

$Users = Get-Content $UserListPath

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $UAC = Get-Aduser -Identity $user -Properties "useraccountcontrol" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "useraccountcontrol" | Out-String

    If($UAC -eq "514"){
        Write-Host "$user Is Disabled" -ForegroundColor Red
    }


    elseif ($UAC -eq "66050") {
        Write-Host "$user Is Disabled" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) attribute is a bit flag. That means that each digit of the binary number is a flag that has a different meaning.

So while a value of `514` and `66050` do mean disabled, there are lots of other decimal values that also mean it's disabled. What *really* makes the account disabled is if the second bit is `1`. You can see this in the binary representation of those numbers:

> 514 = ‭0010000000**1**0‬
>
> 66050 = ‭000100000010000000**1**0‬

The only sure way to determine that an account is disabled is by using a [bitwise operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6#bitwise-operators) to check the right bit.

But there is also no point converting the `userAccountControl` to a string like you are.

So the inside of your loop should look something like this:

```
$UAC = (Get-Aduser -Identity $user -Properties "useraccountcontrol").useraccountcontrol

If ($UAC -band 2) {
    Write-Host "$user Is Disabled" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Works Like a Charm!!
Thanks So Much!

Answer (score 1):

You could even skip checking the useraccountcontrol property entirely, and look into the "Enabled" property.

Example:

```
$UAC = Get-Aduser -Identity $user -Properties "useraccountcontrol" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Enabled"
```

Unfortunately, i'm not a member of a domain, and don't have AD Cmdlets installed, but this should give you a True or False value back. (Unsure if string or boolean)